# Fetch youtube video resolution in python pytube

Tags: python, pytube

I am trying to make a youtube video downloader using pytube.
So, I need different video resolution which is available for this video(example: 360p, 480p, 720p...)

my code is given bellow:

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube("https://youtu.be/xyzxyzxyz")
print(yt.streams[0])
```

output:

```
<Stream: itag="18" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.42001E" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">
```

data type of this output is:

```
<class 'pytube.streams.Stream'>
```

now I want to fetch this (res="**360p**") separately.

how can I do it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to download the video in 360p?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try this:

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=27&v=RjLH2vE5rpk")
print(yt.streams.get_highest_resolution().resolution)
```

Output:

```
360p
```

Comment: thank you. it's working. i'm looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **filter** method defined on [api](https://pytube.io/en/latest/api.html#pytube.query.StreamQuery.filter). Hence:

```
streams = yt.streams.filter(res="360p")
```

Example:

```
from pytube import YouTube
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVPZM_jy-sk&ab_channel=MOKS346'
yt = YouTube(url)
streams = yt.streams.filter(res="360p")
for s in streams:
    print(s)
```

Output:

```
<Stream: itag="18" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.42001E" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">
<Stream: itag="134" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.4d401e" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="243" mime_type="video/webm" res="360p" fps="30fps" vcodec="vp9" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="396" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="30fps" vcodec="av01.0.01M.08" progressive="False" type="video">
```